# How to split date and time value to a time

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
2016年03月12日 9時00分
```

This is returned by `$this->input->post(date_time)`.I want to show only `0900`. How to get this output by above one?

Comment: You should provide a [MCVE]. Provide example input.

Answer (score 0):

There is some unclear charectors in your date string, If the date string is in correct format you can use the below code to get only time part.

```
$dd = "2016-03-12 9:00";
echo date("Hi",strtotime($dd));
```

May be this will help you